# Movie where reality is being faked and polished

Tags: story-identification, movie

So I watched this movie a while ago about this dude who is some sort of police officer or something like that.  I don't remember the specifics but I think people were implanted with some sort of a chip or given some sort of a drug to distort their reality.  For instance, I remember this one scene where he and another dude are getting food, and he has these flashes while looking at the burger.  In one second he sees it like everyone else, meaty, nice, and fresh, and all of a sudden it's rotten and full of worms.  It freaks him out but no one else but him sees it that way.

After some events he is saved/kidnapped by these "resistance" people who remove the chip or remove the mind altering chemicals and show him the real world and explain that they are the few who refuse to live a lie and they want to expose the truth to the rest of the people.

I only remember the ending scene where they turn off the whatever was causing the simulation and you see the whole city becoming ruined and post apocalyptic.

Comment: *Mindwarp* has aspects of this, but I don't think it matches on enough points.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but unfortunately that's not it.

Comment: Can you pin down what "a while ago" means to you? Are we talking years or decades?

Comment: Ok, so as far as I can tell by the animations and effects i remember the movie year ranges from 1995-2007.I did search every database I could get my hands on and imputing every detail i remember, but at this point I'm starting to believe the movie doesn't exist ....

Comment: *[Dark City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_City_(1998_film))?*

Comment: I don't think this is it but it reminded me of the Futurological Congress and thence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Congress_(2013_film)

Comment: Probably a dupe of this; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66850/what-tv-movie-has-a-man-seeing-glimpses-of-dystopia-in-his-utopian-world

Comment: The food sounds a little like eXistenZ

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like [Virtual Nightmare](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0244290/). There are several scenes where the hero sees food rotting, but this is probably the one you're remembering