# Movie about cop with a control chip in his head which breaks

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia, mind-control

In the 90s or early 00s I watched a film about a corporation who controlled society. All citizens had a chip in their heads, that substitutes and decors their reality. For example, a future style city in real vision is a rusty factory location and tasty burgers are bread full of protein larvae.

In the plot the chip in the main character's head broke and this cop starts to see world in real state.

Comment: A cop or an advertising executive? ; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/66852/20774

Comment: A cop, or a drifter? Sounds like They Live (1988) where a guy gets a pair of sunglasses that reveals the real world to him, and the alien invasion.

Comment: @MEZON any input on the movies Valorum and Jack Nimble suggested?

Comment: @Jenayah it is not a jack nimble, but i can't findout for Valorum movie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it, *[Nightmare City 2035](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0910868/)*. It was filmed in Bulgaria at 2007, so I thought that it was from the late 90s. Good plot and ideas, but bad anything else. Not worth a second glance.

> The future. The corrupt regime broadcasts the illusion of a beautiful city to the chip in your head, when in fact the city is in ruins. The rebels know the truth and seek to foment revolution.

### Trailer

Comment: Unfortunately, I've neither found an English language trailer nor one with the reality breaking down.