# What film has corporations ruling the world and consumers with a device attached to their head?

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a trailer I saw a few times, but I failed to note the name.  It's a similar dystopia to *The Matrix* in some ways, but one where corporations have taken over the world and people have some kind of device attached to the head.  The entire world revolves around consumers consuming.

There seem to be only a few people who don't have anything attached to their head?  The action takes place in an urban setting; I remember a city centre.

So, not *The Matrix* (1999) or *Surrogates* (2009).  I recall seeing this trailer in ~2013.

Comment: Obligatory mention of [this meta topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) on how to ask a good question. Was this live-action? Animation? Were they talking in English? Did you see this online? Before a DVD you were watching? In the theatres?

Comment: Virtual Nightmare? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/66852/20774

Comment: Wait, isn't this real life? Except that mobile phones aren't attached to our heads yet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Could this be [Branded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_5YSW7hRbA) from 2012? I haven't seen it but the trailer features heavy consumerism and some scenes of quasi-organic looking things attached to people's heads. The blu-ray summary says:

> BRANDED is a dark and mind-bending journey into a surreal, dystopian society where mega-corporations have unleashed a monstrous global conspiracy to get inside our minds and keep the population deluded, dependent and passive. One man's quest to unlock the truth behind the conspiracy will lead to an epic battle with the hidden forces that really control our world.

Comment: Yes, that's it - thanks! Edit: ooh, 4.7 at IMDB...

Comment: @NeepNeepNeep I've been very surprised more than once when a film I liked a lot ended up disliked by critics or viewers, so I stopped caring about that much.

Comment: @NeepNeepNeep Those who give the movie bad reviews are obviously part of a conspiracy to prevent people from learning the truth :)

Comment: @NeepNeepNeep Who knows, maybe this one will help you complete the [unpopular opinion challenge](https://xkcd.com/2184/).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst we have an accepted answer, other people who go looking for an answer to this question may be looking for [Harrison Bergeron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Bergeron_(film)), which is a loose adaptation of the [short story of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Bergeron) by Kurt Vonnegut.

In the short story, people who are more than averagely intelligent are forced to wear "handicaps" to limit their ability to think, which include distorting lenses and headphones which produce distracting (and at times painful) noise.  The film takes a more direct approach to handicapping intelligent people, fitting them with headbands which impede their brain function.

In both the short story and the film, people are reduced to being simply unquestioning vehicles for consumption of products.