# Sci-fi movie in which a drug causes people to think the world is perfect

Tags: story-identification

I am searching for a sci-fi movie. In this, the world seems to be a really perfect place. However a guy gets visions that suggest that this is all an illusion and the world is actually sort of nightmarish. In the end he (and a woman) find out that the world is actually neither, but just pretty run-down and like a desert. The nightmarish vision were supposed to scare people to find out more about the situation. The illusions are made from the government to make people compliant with the help of a drug called "Arora", I think. It might be 10 to 15 years that I saw the movie. Any idea what it was called?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66850/what-tv-movie-has-a-man-seeing-glimpses-of-dystopia-in-his-utopian-world/66852 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6751/what-old-movie-had-people-living-in-a-simulated-world-of-bar-coded-cardboard-pro/6764.

Comment: Dupity doo dah, Dupity day. My oh my, what a wonderful day.

Comment: How is the OP supposed to know that the answer to this question is the same as the answer to a different question? Would **What is the Meaning of Life** be a duplicate of **What is 6 * 7**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be **Virtual Nightmare**? It was a made-for-TV film produced in 2000.

[The Internet Movie Database](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0244290/) says:

> Sci-Fi mystery. In the future the world has apparently reached complete perfection, but when Dale suffers a car accident he begins noticing disturbing glitches in the fabric of reality.

That is an extremely common sci-fi trope, but then this message board post has someone talking about "Arora".

> *"Aurora's the newest product or something, but it turns out to be a fully immersible VR device? That sounds like this movie."* (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0244290/board/nest/130254424?ref_=tt_bd_6)

---

Finally, [here is another post from 2008](https://aliensoup.com/threads/trying-to-find-name-of-obscure-tv-sci-fi-movie-with-mind-control-ray.974/) where someone was trying to identify the movie and included more details:

> *Then, as the man looks out on the office floor, something surprising happens. On top of some things, glowing green letters display the name of the thing. "Desk". "Woman". "Chair." ...the whole world starts to look this way. It starts to appear that rather than an illusion, he may be seeing something about the way the world is.*

---

> *Then, he starts to experience a lower layer of reality! All of a sudden, underneath the reality he thought he knew, there's a disgusting, creepy reality.*

---

> *It turns out there's this mind control ray that was set up a long time ago, and it's been blasting these layers of unreality, and keeping these people in illusion. They break the ray.*

---

> *They return to their home town. Now, it turns out there's a layer underneath the "rats" layer: It's all cardboard boxes! All the furniture, cars, houses, are made of plain, generic cardboard boxes. Their clothes are simple neutral burlap sack cloth.*